# add new column if the previous one is not null

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, insert, alter

I need to create sqlite statement that checks if a specific column value is not null then add a new column and insert the new value.

What I already have is this :

```
CREATE TABLE "StuPayment" (
    "PayNumber" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    "StudentName"   ntext,
    "CourseName"    ntext,
    "PayDate"   datetime,
    "CheckNumber"   NUMERIC,
    "Amount"    NUMERIC
)
```

What I want to create is a new payment columns `(PayDate1,CheckNumber1,Amount1)` when a student pays a course cost on two payments or maybe three sometimes.
Thanks for your time reading this.

Comment: I'd recommend making a new row instead of more columns. Adding a column is going to be a nightmare down the road when you have more and more payments.

Comment: i thought about that , but the problem is after a year maybe the table can be up to 10000 rows and that's very difficult to filter or create a report , thanks for your advance mate

Comment: Relational Databases are modeled based upon relationships.  Your approach misses that *each student can make many payments* which means many payment rows per student.  Which is very simple to filter as needed - date or sequence number for instance

Comment: 10,000 rows is not a lot. You're going to have a worse time maintaining adding columns over and over every time there is a payment. Also, as for reporting, you can do a query using group by and other tools to pull data in the same format you're suggesting. It's just not the best choice to design the table that way.

Comment: is there a way to group rows sharing the same StudentName and CourseName using sqlite ?

Comment: @SalimAl-Tarsha Yes it is possible. Implementing a student ID is a great way to go and you can group based on that.

Comment: thanks guys , that was helpfull

Answer (score 1):

No.  Don't do it.  Just record the payments in multiple rows.  You already have a `datetime` column, so each payment is recorded separately.

There are multiple advantages to new rows:

- You can easily search for things like `amount > 1000` and not have to worry about extra columns.
- You can use an index to search on the payment columns, such as getting all payments on a particular date.
- `PayNumber` uniquely identifies each payment.
- You don't have to reserve space for empty values in all the rows.
- Adding new payment methods (say credit cards, debit cards, direct debit, or other mechanisms) is simpler, because you don't have to multiply the columns for each potential payment.
- You can more easily support payment plans, such as one payment per week.

Your concern about 10,000 rows/year is not relevant in today's world.  Databases and computers are powerful.

If you want to see all the payments that a student has made, you can use:

```
select studentname, coursename, count(*) as numpayments, sum(amount)
from stupayment
group by studentname, coursename;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to have a view created and do whatever manipulation you want as I see theres unclear logical requirement. Go for view Creation

```
   Create view as (Select * from table) ;
   Alter view add column c1 ;
```

Comment: thank you anyway , but i think am going with the previous answer

Comment: Yeah no problem thats the same reason I din ask for changing the original table structure adding in form of rows is the only thing you should do